# "Lecture notes in" or "Lecture notes on"

Tags: prepositions, differences, american-english, british-english, prepositional-objects

I have seen both options used interchangeably, is there a reason why?

- Example with ***on***: https://www.springer.com/series/15362

  > Lecture Notes **on** Data Engineering and Communications Technologies
- Example with ***in***: https://www.springer.com/series/7818

  > Lecture Notes **in** Electrical Engineering

What would then be the correct use in this case:

1. Lecture notes *on* predictive control
2. Lecture notes *in* predictive control

Comment: "Theories on something" and "theories in something" mean different things (albeit the difference is often subtle). "English arose from Proto-Germanic" is a theory on the origin of English, and a theory in linguistics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[american-english](/questions/tagged/american-english)

"On" to me is a shorthand for "on the topic of," e.g. "Lecture Notes on (the topic of) Data Engineering and Communications Technologies," while "in" is a shorthand for "in the field of," e.g. "Lecture Notes in (the field of) Electrical Engineering."

You would not say * "the field of data engineering and communications technologies," nor * "the topic of Electrical Engineering" (except in certain unusual contexts), thus the reversed titles seem wrong to me:

* "Lecture notes in Data Engineering and Communications Technologies" 
* "Lecture notes on Electrical Engineering"

Likewise, * "Lecture notes in predictive control" doesn't sound right to me, so I would use "on" in that context:

"Lecture notes on Predictive Control"

Answer (score 1):

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lecture%20notes%20on%2Clecture%20notes%20in&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows both in use with comparable frequency

[image]